# Map System offline

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing

Guys just a quick question,

I am creating a WEB application in my company. But it's a on the local intranet. So we don't have access to the Internet.

Is there any way of having maps (google, bing, etc) without internet?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I found this:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.2/

I'll try and then let you know

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of offline mapping platforms like MapPoint and Microsoft Streets and Trips but they have recently been retired. Mapping data is large. A single copy of the data in Bing Maps is measured in Petabytes. Offline is just not an option in most cases.

It is possible to create an offline mapping platform and I've helped companies do this in the past, but in most cases limits had to be set, such as limiting to a specific area, or a limited number of zoom levels.